# Rendering a List of sub classes in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, subclass

I'm trying to render a list of a concrete classes derived from a single abstract class in MVC ASP.net 4.5

My index view:

```
@model  List<WebApplication6.Models.BaseClass>
@foreach (var xx in Model)
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(x=>xx)
}
```

My controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new List<BaseClass>
        {
            new AViewModel(), new BViewModel (), new AViewModel(), new AViewModel(), new BViewModel()
        });
    }
```

Concrete Views are located in the Views/Shared folder

AViewModel.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.AViewModel
<h2>A</h2>
```

BViewModel.cshtml

```
@model WebApplication6.Models.BViewModel

<h2>B</h2>
```

When the index renders I don't get any views outputted. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to use a case statement or if/else

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the views in a subfolder called `DisplayTemplates`.  `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/AViewModel.cshtml`